# Delete Sqlite Database file which is in progress state

Tags: c#, sqlite, file, ado.net

Scenario: I have a text file which have large number of data and this data inserted into sqlite table using c#. I have two events(button) one is run and second one is stop, in run button click event the data is inserted into from txt file to sqlite if in between I clicked on stop button then I want to delete the file in which the data inserted.
If some one please help me how to stop the insertion of record in stop button event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

declare and assign the value

```
    int counter = 0;
```

Set the counter value to 1 in stop click

```
    private void btnStop_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ki = 1;
    }
```

In button run method chech the counter value

```
     private void btnLoad_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
      {
        try
        {
            Application.DoEvents();
         foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(txtInput.Text))
                    {
                        if (ki == 1)
                        {
                            return false;
                        }

                    ///Insert Query 
                     }
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can enter code in your delete event to interrupt the query using SQLITE_INTERRUPT.

See the following link that describes SQLITE_INTERRUPT: https://www.sqlite.org/c3ref/interrupt.html

I did not realize that was a C interface and not C# but you can do something like this:

```
    SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection();
    SQLiteCommand cmd;
    SQLiteTransaction transaction;

    private void runCommand()
    {
        using (conn = new SQLiteConnection(""))
        {
            using (transaction = conn.BeginTransaction())
            {
                //Do your work here
                cmd.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM TABLE...";
                transaction.Commit();
            }
        }
    }

    private void btn_cancel_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        cmd.Cancel();

        //OR

        transaction.Rollback();
    }
```

Comment: can you provide a generic example to help clarify what your answer?

Comment: Hi @@Edgar Mora I have got the error message "Cannot access a disposed object.". actually i have tried this type of similar thing. actually the file is still in progress state.

Comment: Are you able to show me a sample of what you have tried? @NidhiTiwari